# Read some file in a bunch of excel files in a folder

Tags: r

I have a big folder, with 2000 files named from 1.xlsx,2.xlsx ,... 2000.xlsx , 
I can read all of them by this way but I just want to read from the file 400 to 1000. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

Comment: Sort the order of file names in the object `file.list` and then subset it to get only the data you want

Answer (score 0):

One quick way might be

```
df.list <- lapply(paste0(400:1000,".xlsx"), read_excel)
```

Answer (score 0):

you were close.

```
lapply(file.list[400:1000], read_excel)
```